# Cant fetch data from child component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

So this is my parent component

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    task: '',
  }
  clicked = () => {
    todoArr.push({id: idcount, text: this.state.task, completed: false})
    idcount++
    this.setState({task: ''})
  }
  changeComletedStatus = props => {
    console.log(props.id)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Todo">
        {todoArr.map(todo => <ShowArr text = {todo.text} key = {todo.id} id = {todo.id} completed = {todo.completed} changeComletedStatus = {() => this.changeComletedStatus}/>)}
        <h1 className = "centered">ToDo App</h1>
        <input value = {this.state.task} type="text" placeholder = "..." onChange = {(e) => this.setState({task: e.target.value})}/>
        <button onClick = {this.clicked}>Add</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Todo
```

and my child component

```
import React from 'react'

const ShowArr = (props) => {
    let id = props.id
    console.log(props.id)
    return (
        <div className="showArr">
            <p className="singleTask">
                {props.text}    
            </p>
            <button onClick = {props.changeComletedStatus(id)}>X</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ShowArr
```

The problem is changeCompleteStatus. My console.log prints `undefined`. Can you explain to me why it doesn't print id I need and how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parent, you don't need to write it as a callback.  You can just do

```js
changeComletedStatus = {this.changeComletedStatus}
```

The way you had it would need to be `changeComletedStatus = {() => this.changeComletedStatus()}` to actually call the function, but its not necessary as you're not passing any arguments.

In the child, use the callback syntax and call your function with the `id`:

```js
<button onClick = {() => props.changeComletedStatus(id)}>X</button>
```

Also, your `changeComletedStatus` is expecting an object with an `id` property on it...but you're just passing it an `id`.  Redefine the arguments for `changeComletedStatus` like so:

````js
  changeComletedStatus = id => {
    console.log(id)
  }
```
````